# Setting value of nested object using square backets returns undefined

Tags: javascript, object, nested

I'm trying to set value of a nested object's property. On Jsbin my first case works well. On my local code -the second case-, it fails. I can't figure out why.

jsbin snippet:

```
var obj= {a:{}}
obj["a"]["b"]="bValue";
console.log(obj) // return a valid object
```

My local code snippet :

```js
let userData = { a: {} }

function nestedValue(a, b) {
  if (userData[a][b] === undefined) {
    console.log("set a")
    userData[a][b] = "here"
    console.log("set b: ", userData[a][b]) // return undefined
  }
}
nestedValue("fruit", "apple")
```

I'm wondering why the second case returns me undefined in console.log? 
Any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: It does not even reach the first logging statement, see snippet - `userData.fruit` does not exist, so trying to check (or set) `userData.fruit.<anything>` throws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let userData = {};

function nestedValue(a, b) {
  if(!!userData[a] === undefined) {
     userData[a] = {};
  }

  if (userData[a][b] === undefined) {
    console.log("set a")
    userData[a][b] = "here"
    console.log("set b: ", userData[a][b]) // return undefined
  }
}
nestedValue("fruit", "apple")
```

In the above example, you are using `bracket` notation which will use the actual value of the key. `fruit` in this case.

So it expecting the initial object which has property called `fruit`

```
var obj= { fruit :{}}
```

-

```
userData[a][b]

let userData = { fruit : {} } // will work for the above use case.
```

is not the same as

```
userData.a.[b]

let userData = { a : {} } // will work for the above use case.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try defining your object as

```
var obj = new Object()
```

```js
var obj = new Object();

function nestedValue(a, b) {
   obj[a] = b;
   console.log(obj);
   return obj;
}

nestedValue("fruit","apple");
```